# ObserveEvent inside shiny module server

Tags: r, shiny

I successfully generated dynamic buttons that are located within my DT table. I associated each button with an event, and the code below works as intended.

[image]

However, **there is a way to trigger the observeEvent function from within the catalog_server rather than from the server app**
.
When I attempted to move the observeEvent into the module_server, it did not display the message, and I am unsure why.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to modify the code so that the observeEvent function can be recognized within the catalog_server?

Reproducible example

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets)

# Get data
get_list_projects <- function() {
  df <- iris
  cbind(df,
        button = sapply(1:nrow(df), make_button("tbl1")),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# button html generator
make_button <- function(tbl){
  function(i){
    sprintf(
      '<button id="btn_%s_%d" type="button" class="btn btn-light"
       onclick="%s"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>', 
      tbl, i, "Shiny.setInputValue('button', this.id); ")
  }
}

catalog_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df_list_projects <- shiny::reactiveVal({
    get_list_projects()
  })

  output[["tbl1"]] = DT::renderDT(
    DT::datatable(df_list_projects(), escape = F)
  )
}

catalog_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(style = "height: 100%",
      class = "jumbotron",
      id = ns("project_panel"),
      shinyWidgets::useSweetAlert(),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               column(12, DT::DTOutput(outputId = ns("tbl1")))
        )
      ))
}

shiny::tagList(
  navbarPage(id = "navbar_header",
             shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
             waiter::use_waiter(),
             collapsible = TRUE,
             tabPanel("Tab1",
                      catalog_ui(id = "catalog_page")))) -> ui

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  shiny::moduleServer(id = "catalog_page",
                      module = catalog_server, session)

  # I would like to MOVE THIS FUNCTION into the catalog_server and have
  # the message still get generated!!!
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    row <- strsplit(input$button, "_")[[1]]
    row <- row[3]
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = paste0("Row ", row, " clicked"),
      size = "s",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you move the observer inside the module, you have to replace `Shiny.setInputValue('button', this.id)` with `Shiny.setInputValue('MODULEID-button', this.id)`. Indeed there is an `input[["button"]]` in the observer, and inside a module it is actually read as `input[[ns("button")]]`.

So I would do:

```r
# Get data
get_list_projects <- function(ID) {
  df <- iris
  cbind(df,
        button = sapply(1:nrow(df), make_button(ID, "tbl1")),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# button html generator
make_button <- function(ID, tbl){
  function(i){
    sprintf(
      '<button id="btn_%s_%d" type="button" class="btn btn-light"
       onclick="Shiny.setInputValue(\"%s-button\", this.id);">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>', 
      tbl, i, ID)
  }
}

catalog_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    df_list_projects <- shiny::reactiveVal({
      get_list_projects(id)
    })
    
    output[["tbl1"]] = DT::renderDT(
      DT::datatable(df_list_projects(), escape = F)
    )
  })
}
```

and in the server: `catalog_server("catalog_page")`.

Comment: Ah, this really works! Thanks!

Or just change 'Shiny.setInputValue('button', this.id);'  with 'Shiny.setInputValue('catalogo_page-button', this.id);'